# Meaning of "by some margin"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Could you please explain the meaning of this? I have it in a sentence - The speaker was, by some margin, the youngest person in the room. I am a translator from English to Czech and I can´t find it anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It means by some non-zero or at least **non-negligible** margin (difference, or delta).  IOW, it means that the person was **considerably** younger than everyone else.

Comment: I agree with your 2nd sentence but what does the first mean? What is 'delta or difference'? I haven''t heard that before :)

Comment: delta is used for the difference in a subtraction, as it is shorter. So if you subtract youngest fellow's age from each of the other's age not only is it positive (thus he is younger), but it is also not near zero.

Comment: I added a comma, and put *difference* first. The three terms mean the same thing in this context: *margin*, *difference*, *delta*. (The Greek letter delta, Δ or δ, is often used in math or science notation to stand for a change in amount: a difference.)

Answer (score 2):

[Margin](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/margin):

> an additional amount or one beyond the minimum necessary.

If the speaker was younger than the others by one year, that would not be a big deal - someone has to be the youngest.

But if he was the youngest by a number of years, that is *a significant margin*.

By some margin, you are saying, *by a number of years*.

Answer (score 1):

He was *noticeably* younger than others. In Czech, this is "zretelne najmladsi".